# Using arrow key navigation together with TabIndex in WinUI 3

Tags: winui-3

I'm trying to work out how to use tab navigation between groups of controls and allow arrow key navigation within those groups in WinUI 1.3. This works great when setting `XYFocusKeyboardNavigation="Enabled"` and `TabFocusNavigation="Once"`. As soon as I start defining `TabIndex` properties on the controls or the containers, though, tab navigation becomes erratic and it's not possible to reach all controls by tab anymore. Here is an example:

```xml
<StackPanel
    HorizontalAlignment="Center"
    VerticalAlignment="Center"
    Orientation="Horizontal"
    TabFocusNavigation="Cycle">
    <StackPanel
        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
        VerticalAlignment="Center"
        Orientation="Vertical"
        TabFocusNavigation="Once"
        TabIndex="3"
        XYFocusKeyboardNavigation="Enabled">
        <Button>Click Me 1</Button>
        <Button>Click Me 2</Button>
        <Button>Click Me 3</Button>
        <Button>Click Me 4</Button>
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel
        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
        VerticalAlignment="Center"
        Orientation="Vertical"
        TabFocusNavigation="Once"
        TabIndex="2"
        XYFocusKeyboardNavigation="Enabled">
        <Button>Click Me 5</Button>
        <Button>Click Me 6</Button>
        <Button>Click Me 7</Button>
        <Button>Click Me 8</Button>
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel
        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
        VerticalAlignment="Center"
        Orientation="Vertical"
        TabFocusNavigation="Once"
        TabIndex="1"
        XYFocusKeyboardNavigation="Enabled">
        <Button>Click Me 9</Button>
        <Button>Click Me 10</Button>
        <Button>Click Me 11</Button>
        <Button>Click Me 12</Button>
    </StackPanel>
</StackPanel>
```

In this example, pressing tab repeatedly alternates the focus between "Click Me 1" and "Click Me 5". Pressing shift+tab repeatedly puts the focus on "Click Me 12" and leaves it there, no matter how often you type shift+tab.

Setting `TabIndex` on the first button of each StackPanel instead of on the StackPanel itself also breaks tab navigation. Tab then highlights "Click Me 5", then "Click Me 1", then "Click Me 6", then "Click Me 1", always alternating between 1 and 6 from then on. Shift+tab leads to "Click Me 12" and stays there.

I've tried adding `IsTabStop="True"` to the `StackPanel`s. This leads to the panels being an additional tab stop, so you always need to tab twice. I've tried changing this behavior in the code-behind:

```cs
private void StackPanel_OnGettingFocus(UIElement sender, GettingFocusEventArgs args)
{
    if (args.InputDevice == FocusInputDeviceKind.Keyboard && sender is Panel panel)
    {
        args.Handled = true;
        var control = panel.Children.OfType<Control>().FirstOrDefault(static e => e.IsTabStop && e.IsEnabled);
        control?.Focus(FocusState.Keyboard);
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, the call to `Focus()` leads to an unspecified COM exception.

Comment: Seems to be related to this closed [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues/1363). Have you tried updating WinAppSDK to v1.4?

Comment: Just tested and the behavior is unchanged with WinAppSDK 1.4.230913002

Comment: I've created a Github issue: https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues/8942

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your tab navigation needs to circle around each `StackPanel`, try without setting `TabIndex`.

Comment: If this answer solves your problem, please accept it as the answer so we can close this session.

Comment: I numbered the stack panels as index 3, 2, and 1, as my UX requirements are such that I need to define the tab order, as it is not the same as the order of the elements in the XAML file. That is essentially my question: How can I use arrow key navigation yet still be allowed to define the tab order?

Comment: If you need to set `TabIndex`, then also set `IsTabStop=true` on each `StackPanel`. One caveat though. Since the `StackPanel` will get the tab focus, you'll need to hit tab twice.

Comment: I like the approach and have tried that already. I'd then need to prevent the `StackPanel` from receiving focus.

Comment: I have added my findings on this to the question description.

Comment: I posted a workaround based on your suggestion here: https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues/8942 Thanks for the support!

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have two instances of `TabIndex="1"` so delete the second one (the one for buttons 9 to 12). That should address the back tab problem.

Comment: I'm not seeing that. The first column has index 3, the second index 2, and the third index 1.